# JVM and .Net at he same time with Python and Iron Python linking them

Tags: c#, java, python

Can I write a program that uses the Java Virtual Machine as well as the .Net framework at the same time as long as I use Python and Iron Python to link the two aspects of my program.

I would like to make a program/video game using Java (JVM), Python, Iron Python and C#.net (using MS Blend and silverlight). The reasons are the following:

-I already have some of the program done in Java and JavaFX but now want to use MS Expression Suite.
-I already own MS Blend and when I bought (stupidly) I paid $500 for MS Expression Suite without buying MS Visual Studio.
-I would like to learn both C# as well as Java, and Python.
-I would like to use MS Expression suite since I paid so much for it.
-MS Blend is easier to use than Java Swing and Javafx.

If I was more willing to rewrite the program in C# and silverlight this wouldn't even be an issue. Basically I dont want my Java code to go to waste.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just how much Java code have you got? The effort of getting all the bridging to work may well be more than the effort of porting your code to C#.

Comment: You can run python on the jvm with jython, and on clr with iron python, but they're still 2 separate vms/processes, so it would be like getting any 2 processes to work together (i.e., you're going to want a course and well defined/designed interface between the processes).  You could setup you java code to run as a server with some sort of socket/http interface, but I'm guessing it would be easier to port the java code to C#/iron python.